# Typescript: How to create interface based off of enum

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

I have an enum `EEndpoints` that maps to string addresses of local nodes. I want to create an interface/hard-coded object based off of this enum. This is my idea:

```
export enum EEndpoints
{
    MY_REMOTE_NODE = "MY_REMOTE_NODE",
}

export interface EndpointAddresses
{
    PublisherAddress: string,
    RequestAddress: string,
}

export interface EndpointAddressList
{
    for (key in EEndpoints)
    {
        [key] = EndpointAddresses;
    }
}
```

In my code I would then be required to define a constant that implements `EndpointAddressList`:

```
const RemoteNodeEndpoints: EndpointAddressList =
{
    MY_REMOTE_NODE: {
        PublisherAddress: "tcp://127.0.0.1:3000",
        RequestAddress: "tcp://127.0.0.1:3001",
    },
}
```

Alternatively, it would also be nice to define an interface that itself implements `EndpointAddressList`, i.e:

```
interface ImplementedEndpointAddressList
{
    MY_REMOTE_NODE: {
        PublisherAddress: "tcp://127.0.0.1:3000",
        RequestAddress: "tcp://127.0.0.1:3001",
    },
}
```

I'm also open to feedback if using an `enum` as the basis for properties in an interface is an anti-pattern. However, it does seem like a useful tool for me to centrally define a set of hard-coded endpoints and then have compile time checks that I have configured the sub-properties of those endpoints.

Comment: I don't really understand what benefit you are trying to leverage an `enum` for here. If you declare the interface `EndpointAddressList` to simply have explicitly declared fields, with each one corresponding to a `EndpointAddress`, where does that fall short?

Comment: The idea is that you would export the enum and make that available to callers. The callers would then pass in an enum argument that would be used inside the class to lookup addresses.

`RequestAddress` and `PublisherAddress` are protocol-specific details that I want to hide from outside classes. Instead, they would just have a string name for the endpoint. e.g. `EEndpoints.USER_ACCOUNTS` or something. This would be passed in to a function like `Subscribe(aEndpoint: EEndpoints, aTopic: string)`